# custom HandleErrorAttribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i want to display all errors on the same page (without redirecting/changing page content) where it was happened (e.g. javascript alert) and i think that the error-page could load like PartialView.
i try to create custom HandleErrorAttribute, but it's not working:

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public string PartialViewName { get; set; }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = new PartialViewResult();
        result.ViewName = PartialViewName;
        filterContext.Result = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    this.View("Error").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
}
```

More info (including how to make it obey customErrors=RemoteOnly) can be found here:

http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html

Comment: @JoshNoe Works here - what do you see?

Comment: "Oops! Google Chrome could not find blog.dantup.com".  I can get a cached copy from Google on Jan 13th though.  Try clearing your browser's cache maybe?

Comment: @JoshNoe I can fetch it at home and work, multiple machines, definitely not coming from browser cache. Can you resolve the domain? Can you access anything else on the domain? What IP address does it resolve to?